# Default create_users_table throwing max key length error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started my Laravel project by executing these lines of code in my command prompt window.

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs
composer global require laravel/installer
laravel new iezon
```

I then executed the command to build the authentication schemes, I have not edited anything as of yet.

```
artisan make:auth
```

I then headed over to my config folder, and inside `database.php`, I changed the `mysql` to the correct information likewise with the `.env` file that overwrites it.

Now, I create the migration table to check my connection to the database by using:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

And install my tables (default user tables):

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

which then throws me an error in this debug:

```
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\iezon\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezon\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezon\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
```

Any ideas what command I'm missing or doing wrong? I haven't altered any file content other than the `database.php` file and `.env` file with the correct `mysql` information. How can I fix this?

Comment: Here you go: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Cheers @nakov if only I found this link sooner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

````
Go To AppServiceProvider.php in ```app\Providers```
````

and change `boot()` by adding this line

```
\Schema::defaultStringLength(191);


function boot()
{
 \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Laravel uses the `utf8mb4` character set by default, which includes support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a version of MySQL older than the `5.7.7` release or MariaDB older than the `10.2.2` release, you may need to manually configure the default string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the `Schema::defaultStringLength` method within your `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: Oh, wow. I attempted to Google this question but could't put the error into words. This has fixed the issue and all my tables have migrated. Thanks! I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Or upgrade to MySQL v5.7.7 or higher

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and have the newest version, how can I upgrade the MySQL of it? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Not sure on XAMPP as I am a WAMPServer user, where its easy

Comment: But of course you need to think about what version of MySQL will be available on the eventual LIVE hosting server as well!

Comment: That is a good point, I'll look into using WAMPServer now. Also, this is my first time using Laravel, I usually only build my own CMS/MVC framework but I thought, why re-invent the wheel if it exists and is powerful so I might as well make an effort to use and learn it. Thanks for the advice @RiggsFolly

Comment: Actually XAMPP has mariaDB packaged with it now doesn't it?

Comment: So I think you would need mariadb 10.2 or greater

Comment: I have no clue: first time using XAMPP, too. Sounds strange but I'm practically fluent in PHP but have no clue about hosting or what things are or why they are done, just know how to do it lol. Perks of only being self-taught lol (sad face). I'll defo research into it, I really need to learn about service providers but its just finding the time @RiggsFolly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat] @RiggsFolly (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185056/discussion-between-jaquarh-and-riggsfolly).